# the external function is called without waiting for the event triggered in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote a sample jQuery program and found that the function triclick() is called during the document load by jQuery.

If I replace the part1 by part2, then the click() function is working fine. Please clarify on where I am wrong?

I want the element H2 disappear on click of H3. But the element H2 hides on load itself.

Part 1:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $("h1").hide();
    $("h3").click(triclick());      
});

function triclick() 
{
    $("h2").hide();
    alert('H2 is hidden');
}
```

Part 2: Works fine on click of

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $("h1").hide();
    $("h3").click(function() 
    {
        $("h2").hide();
        alert('H2 is hidden');
    });     
});
```

The complete program:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've two pass your function inside a anonymous function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("h1").hide();
    $("h3").click(function(){triclick()});      
});
```

Or just:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("h1").hide();
    $("h3").click(triclick);      
});
```

Yous should only pass the reference to the function to the click and not call the function.

Comment: Hi @Anand if this has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the green check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this, though.

Comment: I am new to this site and so learning things. Anyways, thanks

Comment: @Anand, glad to have helped you ;)

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass only name of function. () <- means to execute it

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("h1").hide();
    $("h3").click(triclick);      
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is

> $("h3").click(triclick());

this means ,when "h3" is clicked  it will run the result be returned by the function "triclick"

but here you should transfer the parameter the function name ,not the function executed-result;

you should know the parentheses is an operator in javascript ,when it follow the defined function name ,it will have the function executed in an function expression.

change the code to

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
   $("h1").hide();  
   $("h3").click(triclick);      
});
```

when "h3" is clicked the function triclick will run